# Change background image of UIToolbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitoolbar

How can I change the background image of UIToolbar? I have been able to do this for navigation bar, but not UIToolbar. I do not want to change tintColor. I would like to change the whole image.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Can I give a UIToolBar a custom background in my iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941103/can-i-give-a-uitoolbar-a-custom-background-in-my-iphone-app)

Overriding the drawRect function and creating an implementation of the `UIToolbar` does the trick :)

```
   @implementation UIToolbar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"nm010400.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer 7KV7. I tried this and it doesn't seem to work.   To be clear I am putting this code in the view controller which needs the new toolbar, above the @implementation. Am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: I think its better to subclass uitoolbar

Comment: 7KV7, the method you mentioned works fine on the device, but not on simulator. But yes it seems that subclassing it is a better way of doing it. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code:

```
[myToolbar insertSubview:[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toolbar_40.png"]] autorelease] atIndex:0];
```

Fixed for Simulator 4.3.

Answer (score 1):

since iOS5 you can use the Appearance API:

```
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```