# how can i set the image in background of UItoolbar?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

how can i set the image in background of UItoolbar?
please give the answer in simple word and in sequence of steps.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change background image of UIToolbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348340/change-background-image-of-uitoolbar)

Comment: Step1: enter "iphone uitoolbar background" in search box. Step 2: see any of similar questions already asked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your custom toolbar by extending UIToolBar and override `drawRect` method.

```
@interface XToolBar : UIToolbar {
}
@end
```

And implementation :

```
@implementation XToolBar
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"hede.png"] drawInRect:rect];
}
@end
```

Comment: is i need to create .h and .m file for this ?

Comment: yes. `interface` part is in .h file. and `implementation` part is in .m file. Simply create a class called `XToolBar`

Comment: i creat the new class called XToolBar paste the all code then change the name of pic but toolbar is not change her background

Comment: did you create UIToolBar via Interface Builder ?

Comment: you mean in your code? use `XToolBar *toolBar = [[XToolBar alloc] init];` when you create.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @implementation UIToolbar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"CustomImage.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
```