# UIToolBar: how to set custom Text/Background colour

Tags: iphone, ios, uitoolbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I give a UIToolBar a custom background in my iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941103/can-i-give-a-uitoolbar-a-custom-background-in-my-iphone-app)

Hi everybody,

I'm working on a iOS project with a custom Toolbar. I'm having the following problem:
The color values for the icons are simply ignored during run time on he device. The text is always white (so i think only the grayscale value is used). Does anyone of you know how to solve the problem?

thx in advance.

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941103/can-i-give-a-uitoolbar-a-custom-background-in-my-iphone-app) thread.

Comment: Are you setting the Tint colour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize UIToolBar.

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ToolBar_background.png"];
UIImageView *anImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
[aToolBar insertSubview:anImageView atIndex:0];
[anImageView release];
```

Create UIButton

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Add your button to the toolbar.

```
[aToolBar addSubview:myButton];
```

Try this.