# is there a toolbar background image possible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, background, uitoolbar

i´ve seen apps where the toolbar had a custom image as background. in the class reference of UIToolbar i can´t find any property for that. in IB there is also no parameter to set a custom image.

is the only way to achieve that an UIView at the bottom that looks like a toolbar?

regards

Comment: Check out this article: [Recreating the iBooks wood themed navigation bar](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/13/wooduinavigation/) Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a property for doing that. However it is achievable using the way mentioned in the accepted answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941103/can-i-give-a-uitoolbar-a-custom-background-in-my-iphone-app) post