# add UIBarButtonItem to UINavigation bar without UInavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

i have a tabbed application and some tabs use a navigation stack. Thats fine,
But the tabs that don't, i want to add a consistant layout.

So I'm wondering how to add barButtonItems to the navigation bar, without navigation stack.

So this wont work (because the navigation stack does not exist)
`self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customItem;`

how can i add custom item to UInavigation bar?

Answer (score 1):

Use interface builder to add a navigation bar to your viewController xib and add bar button item from interface builder.

Comment: Im trying not to use IB for this, mainly because all i have is a table view and a navigation bar, but that may be the only option.

Comment: If you have UINavigationBar binded through IB or code you can add bar button item to the instance of that navigation bar. Just do not use self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customItem; because as you said there is no navigation stack so just bind to the top navigaition bar you have in your view.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care for the navigation aspect of the bar at all, then perhaps you can use `UIToolbar`.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UIToolbar *bar2 = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [self.view addSubview:bar2];
    [bar2 release];
}
```

Comment: This is a valid option, and i initially tried this also, But there is a black border on the bottom of the Navigation bar. Which is on the top of the toolbar. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: This is because the UIToolbar is meant to be on the bottom, hence the black line is at the top (opposite for UINavigationBar).  You can take a look at this post and implement a custom background for your UIToolBar (Second one down, or the selected answer).  Just Get a 1 pixel wide image of the UINavigationBar and put that for the backround of your toolbar.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941103/can-i-give-a-uitoolbar-a-custom-background-in-my-iphone-app

Answer (score 0):

Use below to add custom item to `UINavigationbar` in your `UIViewController` inherited class.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"my Button" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(ClickButton:)];
```

**EDITED:**

For the controller which doesn't use navigation stack, you could consider using the `UIToolbar` for them.

Comment: Read my post, NavigationItem doesn't do anything without a navigationController.

Comment: @cream-com :I think, You could not use `navigationBar` without `navigation stack`,

Comment: yes, this is valid, but there is a UI discrepancy with using a toolbar and navigation bar, because of the black border (sigh)

Comment: u could use the below two property to get the exact look and feel like navigation bar ... **@property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *tintColor
@property(nonatomic) UIBarStyle barStyle**